# How to get objectApiName in community on LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I'm trying to get the sObject Name on community record page. 
Getting the recordId works! But getting the sObject name does not.. Can I get it automatically in community ?

followed this doc which says its possible :
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_object_context

Thats my Lightning Web component markup:

XML :

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>My LWC</masterLabel>
    <description>Community Component</description>
     <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
        <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Record ID" default="{!recordId}" description="The value should be {!recordId}."/>
        <property name="objectApiName" type="String" label="Object Name" description="Bind the page's {!objectApiName} to the component variable" default="{!objectApiName}" />
    </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>`
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
export default class MyComp extends LightningElement {
        @api recordId;
        @api objectApiName;

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('recordId ' + this.recordId); // this works
    console.log('objectApiName ' + this.objectApiName); // this does not WORK ??
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions for the metadata binding for objectApiName?

Comment: What does this means? Not sure I understand.

Comment: Sorry, I now see that your "component markup XML" wasn't your template (which I assumed it was and ignored) but rather is the metadata XML file with the property binding for objectApiName. Given you did this, please can you add the URL for the page it isn't working in? I ask because the page you linked specifically says "This approach works only for components where the {!objectApiName} is in the route" which tells me the page URL must include the object type as a step for this to work.

Comment: Which Page URL? Can you be a little more clear. My example followed the documentation link posted - the whole point here is to get the objectApiName dynamically.. if I need to mention the name specifically (hard code) it’s going against the idea here.

Comment: I literally mean the URL shown in the browser when you visit the page, in the community, where you see the problem with your component.

Comment: I see the problem already in the community builder when simply dragging the component on the community page.  My browser console logs shows that nothing was captured in property objectApiName.

Comment: That could be a red herring with how the community builder works vs how this value is picked up...? Seems to me you should see if it works in the actual community deployment and if not capture what the URL looks like.

Comment: Yes.That’s seems to be working outside of builder. Great thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the discussion on this question it appears that there is a bug in the community builder that doesn't ensure the objectApiName value is made available, via the target property binding in the LWC's meta XML, unlike the recordId which seems to work.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_object_context) does state, under Access Object Context in Communities, that a property must be used and includes the example:

```
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
        <property
            name="objectApiName"
            type="String"
            label="Object Name"
            description="Automatically bind the page's object name to the component variable"
            default="{!objectApiName}" />
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

It is clear that this *should* work without explicitly stating the object's API name due to the default here (as per recordId).

The only caveat specified is:

> NOTE This approach works only for components where the {!objectApiName} is in the route.

Either there's a bug or the specific usage here doesn't have the object API name as part of the URL.

Comment: This is not a bug. This mean tho work like this. Please see the below answer. Hope this will help. Thanks !!

Comment: Hi. Please include link, in your answer, to documentation that explains this is the intention. Otherwise how can you know it isn't a bug?

Comment: Hi Phil, I didn't find any specific documents which clearly states that but with my previous experience in Aura component this is how the behaviour was and same worked here also for me. This might help you. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_object_context          Thanks!!

Comment: Sadly this is still an issue in 2022 :(

Comment: 2023 still an issue)

Answer (score 0):

Communities don’t automatically bind objectApiName to a component’s template like it does for recordId. With the below property:

We need to explicitly set the objectApiName in the community builder like below.

[image]

Hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: what you say goes against what the documentation states, except for the case where the object API name isn't part of the URL. I have updated my answer accordingly.